# classList.toggle() is being applied only to last item

Tags: jquery, for-loop, addeventlistener

I'm applying eventlistener from a loop to a dropdown menu, but only the last item has its class toggled no matter which item is being clicked on.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            var item = document.querySelectorAll('#dropdown .hasSubMenu');
            var len = item.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var items = item[i];
                var menuItem = items.querySelector('.filter');

                menuItem.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    items.classList.toggle('open');
                });
            }
        });
```

The class 'open' is being added only to the last item from the loop.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Changing `var items = item[i];` to `let items = item[i];` should do the trick. (Though I'd use `let` for all variables.)

Comment: Thank for the advice. I'm new to this complicated Javascript universe. Lots of things to learn and hard to keep the pace

Comment: *I'm new to this* - you'll find things easier if you use the correct plurals/singular for your variable names.  item*s* is plural so should be the for the collection `let items = document.querySelectorAll('#dropdown .hasSubMenu')`  then you have `items.length` and `let item = items[i]` which can help you be sure you're using the correct variable.

Comment: @freedomn-m, sure, you're right. though in my mind I was like item at "i"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) helped me correct my mistake. I didn't know there was differences between `let, var,` etc. So among all the excellent solutions, I choosed changing all my vars from `var x` to `let x`. This is how I fixed my issue.